# Execute parametrical query in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is it possible to execute query like

```
SELECT * FROM `COMMENTS` WHERE `create_date` >= :userInputDate
```

so that when I run it workbench will ask me about parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The closest you can get is to use session variables, like:

```
set @a = 1;
set @b = 2;

select * from table where @a > column1 and @b < column2;
```

This would of course still mean you have to change the values manually in the script, but at least you can run this as a whole in MySQL Workbench instead of rerunning each statement individually.